# print next sequence number from a text file in linux shell scripting

Tags: linux

I have a text file contains below content ..

```
1. /u01/data/ABC/ABC_users01.dbf
2. /u01/data/ABC/ABC_users02.dbf
3. /u01/data/ABC/ABC_users03.dbf
4. /u01/data/ABC/ABC_users04.dbf
5. /u01/data/ABC/ABC_users06.dbf
```

I need to print the next sequence number (i.e., 7 in this case) like below using shell script..

```
/u01/data/ABC/ABC_users07.dbf
```

Could you please help..

Comment: Hi. What do you try so far?

Comment: Are the leading numbers `1. ` etc part of the file? Are the numbers in the file names (`01` ... `06`) decimal numbers with leading 0? Do you need to handle the numbers after `99`? Please [edit] your question to answer, don't use comments for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but the while loop will iterate as many times as you want. Since the file name is the exact same (except for the number of the file, and ABC_users number, you can just write it once and iterate as many times as you want. I used 10 iterations as an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do
echo $i". /u01/data/ABC/ABC_users0"$i".dbf"
((i++))
done
```

Comment: Thanks for you response but this is not what i expected.. 

This should print the next sequence number (ex: in our case --  /u01/oradata/DGSTG/users07.dbf) once the loop ends with no value..

Comment: Want to generate the sequence number based on the last value comes in loop 
ex : ABC1_users01.dbf , ABC1_users02.dbf, ABC1_users03.dbf ...ABC1_users12.dbf etc..,   -- It should print next sequence is ABC1_users13.dbf

Comment: @Maheswar I think this is exactly what I did, except that it started from 1 (AS AN EXAMPLE). If you want the next file to be /u01/data/ABC/ABC_users07.dbf, then simply replace i=0 with i=6. Also, I used 10 iterations, but that can also be changed to what you need.